# score integer stuck although it's declared !IsPostBack declared

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this math game below, if the user gives correct answer, the score should increase by 5. However, it is always stuck in 5 and never inceases. I wonder why? I declared !IsPostBack variable so it stops resetting the int except on page refresh, suggestions appreciated.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    int score;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            score = 0;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int sayi1;
        int sayi2;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        sayi1 = rnd.Next(0, 100);
        sayi2 = rnd.Next(0, 100);
        Label1.Text = sayi1.ToString();
        Label3.Text = sayi2.ToString();
    }


    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int entry = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);
        int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text);
        int total = number1 + number2;

        if (entry == total)
        {
            score += 5;
            Label5.Text = score.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            score -= 2;
            Label5.Text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a different score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, try using `static`..

```
static int score;
```

..but this will be application wide.

If this needs to be **per-user**, then you can use a `session` to store the increments.

```
if (Session["Score"] != null)
    Session["Score"] = ((int)Session["Score"]) + 5;
else
    Session["Score"] = 5;
```

Comment: @codingfreak, be careful with static...if this is just something you are messing about with, and not open to multiple users, then it is fine.  However, if you are thinking of making this available to multiple users, then you will need to use `session` or `viewstate`.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `int` from

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    int score = 0;
}
```

You're essentially defining a new integer variable inside the curly braces, and not updating the one defined as a field.